# Steam wallet cooldown problem

Tags: steam

So I added funds to my steam wallet from a new card a week ago. I was disabled from the market for a week. I thought, fair enough, but was a bit annoyed because I wanted to buy a dota 2 announcer. So I waited a week up until today and I bought it. I bought it with some money I had in my wallet from selling a CS:GO gun skin. Later on, I was looking at the market for another CS:GO skin, and I noticed I was banned again! I haven't even made a transaction! Anyone help? I don't want this to happen every time i get something off the market!

Comment: Have you changed your PC? Did you get new hardware or a complete new computer? I was taken out of selling/buying and trading because I got a new pc.

Comment: If I were you I would contact steam here - [https://support.steampowered.com/](https://support.steampowered.com/)

Comment: Steam can suspect accounts that have been signed in on a new computer for awhile for  trading at times. I've had it happen to me when I moved. I just waited it out, but as @caleb said, contacting support is probably good.

Answer (score 1):

Steam should have given you a prompt to validate your credit card, if you've received this prompt, check your transaction history from your bank for a cheap Steam transaction, usually around a dollar or less, copy the exact price, and paste it into the prompt to verify your card, if you were not given this prompt, you may need to directly contact Steam Support, though I must warn you, they are notoriously bad.